# Customize Mail Invite Form (Share)

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

When inviting an external user by email (via Share), we want to customize the script of invitation. We need to change the username to user's email and add a custom field (Telephone).
Is that possible?

Alfresco Community: 4.2

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/end-user-discussions/alfresco-share/customizing-share-invitation-email-02082009-0152) (simple googling) it is located under

*Company Home > Data Dictionary > Email Templates > invite-email.html.ftl*

path in Alfresco. 
However, if you fail to see changes after modifying e-mail template within previous file in Alfresco, check file in share webapp under path

```
share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\site-webscripts\org\alfresco\components\invite\sent-invites.get.html.ftl
```